# how to save image of Jsignature sign into POS popup widget in odoo10?

Tags: javascript, jquery, odoo-10, point-of-sale

---------- JS File --------------

I can create Custom pos popup widget 7 using Jsignature library for draw signature into that. 
var SaleSignPopupWidget = PopupWidget.extend({
    template: 'SaleSignPopupWidget',
    placeholder: "/static/src/img/placeholder.png",

```
show: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.renderElement();
    this.$el.find('> img').remove();
    this.$el.find('.signature > canvas').remove();
    var sign_options = {'lineWidth':'3','decor-color' : '#D1D0CE', 'color': '#000', 'background-color': '#fff','height':'150','width':'450'};
    this.$el.find(".signature").jSignature("init",sign_options);
    this.$el.find(".signature").attr({"tabindex": "0",'height':"100"});
    this.empty_sign = this.$el.find(".signature").jSignature("getData",'image');
    this.$el.find('#sign_clean').click(this.on_clear_sign);
    this.$el.find('#save_sign').click(this.on_save_sign);
},
on_clear_sign: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.$el.find(".signature > canvas").remove();
    this.$el.find('> img').remove();
    this.$el.find(".signature").attr("tabindex", "0");
    var sign_options = {'decor-color' : '#D1D0CE', 'color': '#000', 'background-color': '#fff','height':'150','width':'550','clear': true};
    this.$el.find(".signature").jSignature(sign_options);
    this.$el.find(".signature").focus();
    self.set('value', false);
},
on_save_sign: function(value_) {
    var self = this;
    this.$el.find('> img').remove();
    var signature = self.$el.find(".signature").jSignature("getData","base30");
    var is_empty = signature
        ? self.empty_sign[1] === signature[1]
        : false;
    if (! is_empty && typeof signature !== "undefined" && signature[1]) {
        self.set('value',signature[1]);
    }
```

----------  XML file ---------------

```
<t t-name="SaleSignPopupWidget">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="popup" id="drawsign">
                <div class="header">
                    <strong>Draw your signature</strong>
                    <div class="signature"></div>
                 </div>
                <div class="footer">
                    <div class="button confirm" id="save_sign">
                        Save
                    </div>
                    <div class="button" id="sign_clean">
                        Clear
                    </div>
                    <div class="button cancel">
                        Cancel
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </t>
    <t t-name="FieldBinaryImage-extend">
        <img t-att-src='url'
            t-att-border="widget.readonly ? 0 : 1"
            t-att-name="widget.name"
            t-att-width="widget.node.attrs.img_width || widget.node.attrs.width"
            t-att-height="widget.node.attrs.img_height || widget.node.attrs.height"
            t-att-tabindex="widget.node.attrs.img_tabindex || widget.node.attrs.tabindex"
        />
    </t>
```